# Code highlighting in LaTeX for Swift

Tags: swift, latex, syntax-highlighting

I found some solution with listings or minted to put source code into my LaTeX document but I would like to have Swift code highlighted. Any hints ?

Comment: When I wanted to include large amounts of C# code in a document recently, I found it convenient to use Pygments (pygments.org) in a pre-LaTeX processing step. Unfortunately they don't list Swift as a supported language at present.

Comment: What exactly is your problem using minted? It should support Swift out of the box (if Pygments 2 is installed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swift works out of the box with minted:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{swift}
    let x = 42
    println("Hello, \(x)!")
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

with `xelatex -shell-escape x` produces

[image: screenshot]

Note, however, that this requires Pygments 2 to be installed.

Comment: Ok making a new document using your code its working fine, using my own tex project it sais : ! Undefined control sequence.

Comment: @FelixM Well that’s an error in the document then. We can’t diagnose that without seeing the document. Did you include the relevant packages? Did you verify that you’re using the command correctly?

Comment: I made a new Project copied everything and it´s working now... it´s the same code i don´t know why it´s not working in my old project !? Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package.

While I'm not sure if Swift is already part of the supported languages, adding your own language definition is not that difficult.
See e.g. [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89574/language-option-supported-in-listings).

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following `listings` configuration recently (note: the code is not correctly colored by StackOverflow but it is correct LaTeX snippet):

```
% Swift syntax highlight definition for listings
% Source: https://gist.github.com/chriseidhof/18dbc1c4eef919eab2c7

\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstdefinelanguage{swift}
{
  morekeywords={
    open,catch,@escaping,nil,throws,func,if,then,else,for,in,while,do,switch,case,default,where,break,continue,fallthrough,return,
    typealias,struct,class,enum,protocol,var,func,let,get,set,willSet,didSet,inout,init,deinit,extension,
    subscript,prefix,operator,infix,postfix,precedence,associativity,left,right,none,convenience,dynamic,
    final,lazy,mutating,nonmutating,optional,override,required,static,unowned,safe,weak,internal,
    private,public,is,as,self,unsafe,dynamicType,true,false,nil,Type,Protocol,
  },
  morecomment=[l]{//}, % l is for line comment
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, % s is for start and end delimiter
  morestring=[b]", % defines that strings are enclosed in double quotes
  breaklines=true,
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
  numbers=left,
  captionpos=b,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  basicstyle=\linespread{1.0}\ttfamily\footnotesize, % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102728/129441
}

\definecolor{keyword}{HTML}{BA2CA3}
\definecolor{string}{HTML}{D12F1B}
\definecolor{comment}{HTML}{008400}

\lstset{
explpreset={},
  language=swift,
  inputencoding=utf8x,
extendedchars=\true,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  showstringspaces=false, % lets spaces in strings appear as real spaces
  columns=fixed,
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\color{keyword},
  stringstyle=\color{string},
  commentstyle=\color{comment}
}
```

Comment: In the line `inputencoding=utf8x` I had to change it to `utf8` to get it compiling. Then it worked like a charm.